# What are the countries in which movies have been released all the years (for which we have records)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table called Movies

MovieID | MovieName | LaunchYear | ProducerID | DirectorID | Country | Budget

As it says in the title, I have to select the countries that have had a movie launched every year that I have a record of. Any suggestions, please? I thought I would use count to see the COUNT distinct = COUNT for a certain country but then I would have to somehow select that country.

[image: screenshot of table data]

This is a sample of the database

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: you know you can edit the question? Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Images are pretty worthless as we can't use them to easy reproduce your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the distinct years for each country:

```
select country
from movies
group by country
having count(distinct launchyear) = (select count(distinct launchyear) from movies)
```

Comment: *"It is already distinct country since I use group by country."* nevermind running downstairs to get some coffee..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with off the top of my head:

```
select distinct country
from movies m1
where not exists (
    select *
    from movies m2
    where m2.launchyear not in (
        select distinct m3.launchyear
        from movies m3
        where m3.country = m1.country
    )
)
```

It's probably not very efficient, but then you didn't provide sample data, so it's also untested. Good luck! :-)